# How to properly initialize bIsFocusable in UMG derived class' constructor in UE5.2.1

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

In UE version 5.2.1, there is a warning(check following infomation) when I comile some code which change `bIsFocusable` in runtime, so I'd like to init it in constructor, so I write following code

> Direct access to bIsFocusable is deprecated. Please use the getter. Note that this property is only set at construction and is not modifiable at runtime. Please update your code to the new API before upgrading to the next release, otherwise your project will no longer compile.

```cpp
// in .h
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Blueprint/UserWidget.h"
#include "MyUserWidget.generated.h"

/**
 * 
 */
UCLASS()
class MUTIPLAYER_DEMO_API UMyUserWidget : public UUserWidget
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
public:

    UMyUserWidget(const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer);

};
```

and in .cpp file:

```cpp
// in .cpp
#include "MyUserWidget.h"
UMyUserWidget::UMyUserWidget(const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer): Super(ObjectInitializer),
bIsFocusable(true)//compile error

{
    //I have understood the following code is not a init,it's a assignment. 
    //using init-list above is a init
    //bIsFocusable = true;

}
```

I also tried

```cpp
#include "MyUserWidget.h"
UMyUserWidget::UMyUserWidget(const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer): Super(ObjectInitializer),
UUserWidget::bIsFocusable(true)//compile error

{


}
```

the compile error message is same:

> illegal member initialization: 'bIsFocusable' is not a base or member

[image]

any advice? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had no issues by doing the following:

**Header**

```
UCLASS()
class UMyUserWidget : public UUserWidget
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    UMyUserWidget(const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer);
};
```

**Code**

```
UMyUserWidget::UMyUserWidget(const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer) : Super(ObjectInitializer)
{
    bIsFocusable = true;
}
```

As far as I am aware, assigning this value *in* the constructor is fine in this regard.